# macOS unable to compile any C++ code with

Tags: c++, r, macos, rcpp, clang++

I am unable to compile any Rcpp code in Rstudio on macOS.

The file I am testing it just the file that opens when you do File > New File > C++

Below:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// This is a simple example of exporting a C++ function to R. You can
// source this function into an R session using the Rcpp::sourceCpp 
// function (or via the Source button on the editor toolbar). Learn
// more about Rcpp at:
//
//   http://www.rcpp.org/
//   http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html
//   http://gallery.rcpp.org/
//

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector timesTwo(NumericVector x) {
  return x * 2;
}
```

However this does not compile.

```
364 warnings and 20 errors generated.
make: *** [test2.o] Error 1
clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Users/annaleigh/Documents/GitHub/delabel" -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c test2.cpp -o test2.o
Error in Rcpp::sourceCpp("Documents/GitHub/delabel/test2.cpp") : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.
```

If I check out the "source Cpp" tab I see
/Library/Frameworks.R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h
Line 5 source file is not valid UTF-8

Comment: I am *truly* sorry for this but have exactly *zero* influence over random decisions by Apple coupled with less-than-ideally-communicated changes required from R itself.  In short, you want some blog post by James who may pipe in as well.  Start here:  https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/cpp/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos/

Comment: And this is likely a duplicate so someone may close this too.